# piwik independent opt-outs for multiple domains

Tags: matomo

I use a piwik installation on `/site.xy/piwik` to track 2 sites (`site.xy` and `othersite.xy`)

Is it possible to have different independet opt-out iframes for each domain? Currently it seems, when I opt-out on the first site, the setting is changed on the other, too.

```
<iframe style="border: 0; height: 200px; width: 600px;" src="https://site.xy/piwik/index.php?module=CoreAdminHome&action=optOut&language=de"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible currently. Please see https://github.com/piwik/piwik/issues/6505